# Pandas: remove duplicate record while keeping its old value in dataframe for reference

Tags: python, pandas

I am rewriting a piece of the old code using pandas. My data frame looks like this:

```
index stop_id   stop_name   stop_lat     stop_lon  stop_id2
0         A12     Some St  40.889248   -73.898583      None
1         A14     Some St  40.889758   -73.908573      None
2         B09     Some St  40.788924   -74.846576      None
3         A22     Some St  40.889248   -73.898583      None
```

Note that stop_lat and stop_lon are duplicated for stop_ids 'A12' and 'A22'.

I want to remove the duplicate stop (stop_id='A22') while updating stop_d2 with the removed record's stop_id. So the data frame would look like this:

```
index stop_id   stop_name   stop_lat     stop_lon  stop_id2
0         A12     Some St  40.889248   -73.898583      A22
1         A14     Some St  40.889758   -73.908573      None
2         B09     Some St  40.788924   -74.846576      None
```

Previously I have worked this task with keeping my data in dictionary:

```
d={'A12':['Some St', 40.889248, -73.898583, None],'A14': ['Some St', 40.889758, -73.908573, None],'B09':['Some St, 40.788924,-74.846576, None], 'A22':['Some St', 40.889248, -73.898583, None]}

if d['A12'][1]+d['A12'][2]==d['A22'][1]+d['A22'][2]:
   del d['A22']
   d['A12'][-1]='A22'
```

I want to do similar task in pandas. I know if I just use:
    df=df.drop_duplicates(['stop_lat','stop_lon'])

I will loose the duplicate record and won't retain its id.I need to keep id of the removed stop for proper metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_df = df[df.duplicated(subset = ['stop_lat', 'stop_lon'], keep='first')]

duplicates_df = df[df.duplicated(subset = ['stop_lat', 'stop_lon'], keep = 'last')][['stop_lat', 'stop_lon', 'stop_id']]

new_df.merge(duplicates_df, how='left', on=['stop_lat, 'stop_lon'])
```

Answer (score 1):

***get duplicate mask***

```
cols = ['stop_lat', 'stop_lon']
dups = df.duplicated(subset=cols)
```

***subset df with mask***

```
nodups = df[~dups].set_index(cols)
```

***dups may be duplicated themselves***

```
first_dup = df[dups].drop_duplicates(subset=cols)
first_dup = first_dup.set_index(cols).stop_id
```

***assign accordingly***

```
nodups.loc[first_dup.index, 'stop_id2'] = first_dup
nodups
```

[image]